# Please let me edit the titles of chat bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-bookmarks

In chat, you can bookmark a series of messages, going from your start message to your end message. Afterwards, it'll show up at /rooms/<roomID>/conversation/<title>. This is useful for referring back to specific conversations later on, or to bookmark a special event that happened, or to mark a group of messages for some other reason.

However, once you've created a bookmark... that's it. The only thing that can be done with it is to delete the bookmark.

It would be very useful if a mod or Room Owners (ROs) could then edit a bookmark title after the fact. This would allow for giving conversations clearer titles (such as bookmarks just titled "[reference](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/conversation/reference)" (mod-only link)), or if clarifying becomes necessary later on. As a concrete example, we use bookmarks for our [TTRPG sessions in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118089/pse-rpg-chatroom?tab=conversations). I'd like to go back and edit the titles of certain conversations to be more uniform, and to clarify what campaign each bookmark is associated with, so that you can at a glance if a session was Dungeons & Dragons, Call of Cthulhu, Roll for Shoes...

Could mods and ROs have the ability to rename chat bookmarks after they've been created?

Comment: Worth to mention that only moderators can delete bookmarks, I went looking as RO and there's no such option.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Naturally, the user who created the bookmark can delete it too. A bit related to that: [How do I remove bookmarked chat in a chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151991)

Comment: @Martin nope, can't see any way to delete even my own bookmarks in chat, if there is a way, I'd be glad to learn it. (I'd be very surprised actually, as the basic action of deleting own chat message is not possible after couple of minutes.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I suspect that you're just missing the delete indicator in the UI. At least for bookmarks I've created on chat.MSE, where I'm just a regular user, there's a small deletion button in the top right corner of the bookmark item when looking at the room's bookmark list. I also recall creating and deleting my own bookmarks on chat.SO and chat.SE prior to becoming a moderator (and specifically that I couldn't delete other people's bookmarks at that time).

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foLXq.png) (note that the "X" only appears for bookmarks I made)

Comment: While it's substantially more of a pain in the rear than an actual renaming capability, the workaround for this is to create a new bookmark with a different name and then delete the old bookmark. While that's sub-optimal, I have previously used it to accomplish the task of renaming a bookmark. Obviously, this workaround results in the new bookmark being "created" by the person who "renamed" it and shows the date the "renaming" took place as the creation date, rather than the original creation date. It would be possible to create a userscript which accomplished this automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, @Makyen, but I don't want to mess up the ordering of the bookmarks.

Comment: @Mithical Yeah, that's a consequence of renaming by creating a new bookmark and deleting the old one. Unfortunately, given how unlikely it is that SE will implement this FR in any reasonable timeframe, it's really your only option, as far as I'm aware. If you *really* don't want to disturb the order, then you could recreate all the bookmarks that are after the one you want to rename, but that seems a bit more work than you might want to do. OTOH, it might be that you just want a set of specific bookmarks shown around each other. That would be a smaller number to recreate/delete.

Comment: PSE is likely *[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)* (Stack Exchange site) (not to be confused with *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)* (Stack Exchange site)). RPG is likely *[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)* (Stack Exchange site)

Comment: One should keep in mind the format of URLs too. In the current system, the title uniquely determines the URL. If changing the title would mean changing the URL to, that would mean that various places linking to that conversation would stop working. (For example, if the conversation is linked in a post or a comment on some main/meta site  Or if it is linked in some message in chat.)